# Message Not Redelivered Using Jboss Topic

Tags: java, jboss, jms

I am using `Jboss 4.0.2 GA`

I am using the testTopic defined in the `jbossmq-destinations-service`

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.mq.server.jmx.Topic"
     name="jboss.mq.destination:service=Topic,name=testTopic">
    <depends optional-attribute-name="DestinationManager">jboss.mq:service=DestinationManager</depends>
    <depends optional-attribute-name="SecurityManager">jboss.mq:service=SecurityManager</depends>
    <attribute name="SecurityConf">
      <security>
        <role name="guest" read="true" write="true"/>
        <role name="publisher" read="true" write="true" create="false"/>
        <role name="durpublisher" read="true" write="true" create="true"/>
      </security>
    </attribute>
    <attribute name="RedeliveryDelay">0</attribute>
  </mbean>
```

I have written a same file for publisher and Subscriber ::

```
 package com.nagarro.client;

import javax.jms.*;
import javax.naming.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Chat implements javax.jms.MessageListener {
    private TopicSession pubSession;
    private TopicSession subSession;
    private TopicPublisher publisher;
    private TopicConnection connection;
    private String username;

    /* Constructor. Establish JMS publisher and subscriber */
    public Chat(String topicName, String username, String password)
            throws Exception {
        // Obtain a JNDI connection
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("java.naming.factory.initial",
                "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        properties.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs",
                "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
        properties.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "localhost:1099");
        // ... specify the JNDI properties specific to the vendor

        InitialContext jndi = new InitialContext(properties);

        // Look up a JMS connection factory
        TopicConnectionFactory conFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) jndi
                .lookup("TopicConnectionFactory");

        // Create a JMS connection
        TopicConnection connection = conFactory.createTopicConnection();

        // Create two JMS session objects
        TopicSession pubSession = connection.createTopicSession(false,
                Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        TopicSession subSession = connection.createTopicSession(false,
                Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        // Look up a JMS topic
        Topic chatTopic = (Topic) jndi.lookup(topicName);

        // Create a JMS publisher and subscriber
        TopicPublisher publisher = pubSession.createPublisher(chatTopic);
        TopicSubscriber subscriber = subSession.createSubscriber(chatTopic);

        // Set a JMS message listener
        subscriber.setMessageListener(this);

        // Intialize the Chat application
        set(connection, pubSession, subSession, publisher, username);

        // Start the JMS connection; allows messages to be delivered
        connection.start();

    }

    /* Initialize the instance variables */
    public void set(TopicConnection con, TopicSession pubSess,
            TopicSession subSess, TopicPublisher pub, String username) {
        this.connection = con;
        this.pubSession = pubSess;
        this.subSession = subSess;
        this.publisher = pub;
        this.username = username;
    }

    /* Receive message from topic subscriber */
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            String text = textMessage.getText();
            System.out.println(text);
            if(textMessage!=null){
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }
        } catch (JMSException jmse) {
            jmse.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /* Create and send message using topic publisher */
    protected void writeMessage(String text) throws JMSException {
        TextMessage message = pubSession.createTextMessage();
        message.setText(username + " : " + text);
        publisher.publish(message);
    }

    /* Close the JMS connection */
    public void close() throws JMSException {
        connection.close();
    }

    /* Run the Chat client */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            if (args.length != 3)
                System.out.println("Topic or username missing");

            // args[0]=topicName; args[1]=username; args[2]=password
            Chat chat = new Chat("topic/testTopic", "", "");

            // Read from command line
            BufferedReader commandLine = new java.io.BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            // Loop until the word "exit" is typed
            while (true) {
                String s = commandLine.readLine();
                if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                    chat.close(); // close down connection
                    System.exit(0);// exit program
                } else
                    chat.writeMessage(s);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above I am using `Client_Acknowledge` session mode, But I am not getting the redelivery of message even if I am throwing `NullPointerException` from the `onMessage` method of Listener.

**Kindly let me know if there is any configuration change that is required for redelivery to happen.**

Comment: Is the topic durable? Anyway I am not sure, if it is redelivered at all in case of a *topic* (it's not a queue!). Instead of exiting silently try to call `queueSession.recover()`. I am pretty sure that in case of a queue there is a big difference: Not calling `recover()` means that JBoss waits for a timeout (during the timeout these messages won't be redelivered). Using `recover` means that the messages are "redeliverable" at once.

Answer (score 0):

In case of a topic, messages will be redelivered at once, if you call `topicSession.recover()`, after you have read the messages (for example, in a try/catch block, if an exception happened).

A test using JBoss 7, non-durable topic, `Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE`, and `setMessageListener`:

```
                topicSubscriber.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMessage(Message message) {
                        try {
                            throw new IllegalStateException("Test");
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            try {
                                topicSession.recover();
                            } catch (JMSException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

results in immediate redelivery, 10 times, after that the message is put into the "dead letter queue".

Comment: As per your suggestion, After this code line: `TopicSession pubSession = connection.createTopicSession(false,
                Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);` I added one line i.e. `pubSession.recover();` Also I am using non-durableTopic now,  but it is not working. :(

Comment: Call `recover()` *after* you have read messages. So instead of just doing "nothing" (like `System.exit()`), call it before you exit the application.

Comment: I have read in another post, where you have commented that you are unable to run it in jboss. :)

Comment: @SAM I am not perfect, and JBoss isn't either ... Which posting?

Comment: I am talking about this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567247/jms-auto-acknowledgment-consumer-processing-happens-in-onmessage

Comment: @SAM Yes, you are right: Sorry, I have overlooked in your question that you are using `setMessageListener` (I have run the test without an async listener). I have updated the answer using an async listener. It works as expected (but it's JBoss 7).