# JMS auto acknowledgment consumer processing happens in onMessage

Tags: java, jboss, jms, activemq-classic

I am not able to understand the below point on [JMS AutoAck](http://www.novell.com/documentation/extend52/Docs/help/MP/jms/concepts/details.html) website: 
The below behaviour is followed in `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE`

> Right after the onMessage method returns successfully after invoking the consumer's MessageListener (which might still in progress as per my understanding)

but as per my understanding, the Consumer implements `MessageListener` and does all the processing in the `onMessage()` method (which is implemented by Consumer)

One more question: I am not able to understand the diff between `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` and `DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE`.
What I read is : `DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE` acknowledges lazily and might deliver the same message again, but not able to understand its practical implications.
 Please help me with a practical example where `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` is required and where `DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE` required

---

**Added 5th Sep13** :Adding a point from [Java Redeliver and transaction](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2002/jw-0315-jms.html)

> Consider a failure occurring during message processing. What happens
>   to the message? Will the message be lost or redelivered for successful
>   processing later? The answers to these questions depend upon the
>   **transaction** options you choose.

Answer (score 6):

Some quotes from [Transaction and redelivery in JMS](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2002/jw-0315-jms.html)

---

> **Auto mode**: When a session uses auto mode, the messages sent or received from the session are automatically acknowledged. This is the simplest mode and expresses JMS's power by enabling once-only message delivery guarantee.

Reading a message means acknowledgement as well.
So `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` is simple. But if you are using a `QueueReceiver` without `setMessageListener`, and message processing fails, the message is lost.

---

> **Duplicates okay mode**: When a session uses duplicates okay mode, the messages sent or received from the session are automatically acknowledged just like auto mode, albeit lazily. Under rare circumstances, the messages might be delivered more than once. This mode enables at-least-once message delivery guarantee.

Like `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE`, with less overhead, but the application must be able to deal with duplicate messages. You could use this, if performance matters, and duplicate messages are not a problem.

---

> **Client mode**: When a session uses client mode, the messages sent or received from the session are not acknowledged automatically. The application must acknowledge the message receipt. This mode gives the application (rather than the JMS provider) complete control over message acknowledgement, at the cost of increased code complexity.

Use this approach, if you process one message, and after you have completed this task, then you explicitly call `message.acknowledge()`. If an exception happens during processing, the message is not lost (it will be redelivered).

---

As for the first part of your question, have a look at the Javadoc of 
[AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/Session.html). A quote:

> With this acknowledgment mode, the session automatically acknowledges a client's receipt of a message
>
> either when the session has successfully returned from a call to receive
>
> or when the message listener the session has called to process the message successfully returns.

The linked article conforms to this description (acknowledge only, if `onMessage` is successful).

I have tested this using JBoss 7, using `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` with a `MessageListener`: In case of an exception in `onMessage`, the message is actually **not redelivered**.

Comment: Thanks the the answer . I have two points (1) using AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE with a MessageListener: In case of an exception in onMessage, the message is actually not redelivered on JBoss 4.x (but gets redelivered on ActiveMQ 5.x). I am confused. (2) The linked article states(at least what I understand) acknowlgement(in auto ack mode) is sent right after the onMessage method returns successfully after invoking the consumer's MessageListener(which might still in progress)

Comment: I have found a definitive source, so the linked article is correct. JBoss 4 (your test) and JBoss 7 (my test) do not redeliver (at least not at once), and now I consider this to be a bug. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @ Beryllium Thanks for the updated answer, one question : what do you/java docs mean by session here (is it QueueSession) ?

Comment: Yes, a `QueueSession` or `TopicSession` (which both extend `javax.jms.Session`.